# How can I use if else for regex in flask

Tags: python, regex, flask

In my Flask app, users can type a url for their post. But I want let them to use only `a-zA-Z0-9_-` in the url. If anything else includes in the url more than the `a-zA-Z0-9_-` then I want to return "False" and otherwise "True"
Here is a some demonstrate.

`url = request.form.get('user_url')`

```
if url not in a-zA-Z0-9_- structure :
   return False
else:
   return True
```

How can I use python regex to make this happens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I could make it with @Tim Biegeleisen's answer. Here is the answer.

```
if re.search(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]', url):
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking `re.search`:

```py
if not re.search(r'^https?://[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$', url):
    return False
else:
    return True
```